# Get folders from my msn account onto outlook

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003, hotmail, windows-live-messenger

I have my msn email account setup with a bunch of folders to put all my different emails in. I don't use rules, just drag and drop sort. On my current computer, I have it go to outlook, and all the folders pop up fine. But I set that up 4 years ago, and now I'm setting up a new laptop and have no idea how to get it going again. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check these links
1- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/move-an-outlook-data-file-from-one-computer-to-another-HA001230892.aspx 
2- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287070
3- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/move-your-outlook-data-file-to-another-location-HA001112480.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the [Outlook Hotmail Connector](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/outlook-help/microsoft-office-outlook-hotmail-connector-overview-HA010222518.aspx)?